# Adding a checkbox group to a java menu

Tags: java, checkbox, awt, jmenu

Im trying to add a checkboxgroup to my menu but keep getting a "Cannot find symbol" error.

```
    MenuBar mb = new MenuBar();
    Menu file = new Menu("File");
    Menu colorM = new Menu("Color");
    MenuItem quitM = new MenuItem("Quit", new MenuShortcut(KeyEvent.VK_Q));
    CheckboxGroup cbg = new CheckboxGroup();
    Checkbox cb1 = new Checkbox("Black",cbg,true);
    Checkbox cb2 = new Checkbox("Red",cbg,false);
    Checkbox cb3 = new Checkbox("Blue",cbg,false);
    Checkbox cb4 = new Checkbox("Green",cbg,false);
```

Then in my initialization i have

```
    chatF.setMenuBar(mb);
    mb.add(file);
    mb.add(colorM);
    file.add(quitM);
    colorM.add(cbg);
```

I tried adding a MenuItem and putting the cbg in there but same problem

Comment: If i comment out the colorM.add(cbg) line everything compiles and runs perfectly. The only code i have in the program at the moment is setting up the UI along with adding and removing the listeners so i figured the code for setting up buttons, labels, etc was not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a `CheckboxGroup` to a Menu... you can only add `MenuItem` instances. You can add a `CheckboxMenuItem`, but this doesn't understand `CheckboxGroup` either.

So you need to change the `CheckBox`s to `CheckboxMenuItem`s, add them individually to the menu, roll your own `CheckboxMenuItemGroup` class and use it to bind the `CheckboxMenuItem`s together.

Something like the following should work:

```
public class CheckboxMenuItemGroup implements ItemListener {

    private Set<CheckboxMenuItem>   items = new HashSet<CheckboxMenuItem>();

    public void add(CheckboxMenuItem cbmi) {
        cbmi.addItemListener(this);
        cbmi.setState(false);
        items.add(cbmi);
    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            String itemAffected = (String) e.getItem();
            for (CheckboxMenuItem item : items) {
                // Use this line to allow user to toggle the selected item off
                if (!item.getLabel().equals(itemAffected)) item.setState(false);
                // Use this line to force one of the items to always be selected
                // item.setState(item.getLabel().equals(itemAffected));
            }
        }
    }

    public void selectItem(CheckboxMenuItem itemToSelect) {
        for (CheckboxMenuItem item : items) {
            item.setState(item == itemToSelect);
        }
    }

    public CheckboxMenuItem getSelectedItem() {
        for (CheckboxMenuItem item : items) {
            if (item.getState()) return item;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This should work because `ItemListener`s don't get called when code calls `item.setState()`, only when the user clicks on the item in the menu. Just make sure you only set the state of the items with the `CheckboxMenuItemGroup.selectItem()` call, otherwise you could end up with more than one item selected.

Then you just need to build your menu like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Frame f = new Frame("Test CheckboxMenuItemGroup");
    MenuBar mb = new MenuBar();
    Menu menu = new Menu("Menu");
    CheckboxMenuItem cb1 = new CheckboxMenuItem("Black");
    CheckboxMenuItem cb2 = new CheckboxMenuItem("Red");
    CheckboxMenuItem cb3 = new CheckboxMenuItem("Blue");
    CheckboxMenuItem cb4 = new CheckboxMenuItem("Green");

    CheckboxMenuItemGroup mig = new CheckboxMenuItemGroup();
    mig.add(cb1);
    mig.add(cb2);
    mig.add(cb3);
    mig.add(cb4);
    mig.selectItem(cb1);

    menu.add(cb1);
    menu.add(cb2);
    menu.add(cb3);
    menu.add(cb4);

    f.setMenuBar(mb);

    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    f.setSize(300, 200);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain this a little bit more for me or do you have any other sites i can reference from?

Comment: Firstly, you can only add `MenuItem`s to a Menu, or subclasses of `MenuItem`, such as `Menu`, `PopupMenu` (which makes no sense in this context), and `CheckboxMenuItem` which is exactly the thing you want here. But you also want your `CheckboxMenuItem`s to be exclusive. You can't add them to `CheckboxGroup` so you will have to create a class that works like `CheckboxGroup` but for `CheckboxMenuItem`s, and attach your four `CheckboxMenuItem`s to it. Finally, you need to add your `CheckboxMenuItem`s individually to your `Menu`.

Comment: I'm guessing you don't use an IDE at the moment. If it is practical for you to do so I'd highly recommend you install one like NetBeans or Eclipse, as it can warn you when you are trying to call a method with invalid arguments and suggest appropriate alternatives, even before you try to compile the code.

Comment: @JulianWright I'm trying to use your example for use with the Dock menu on OSX using Java 7 because this only works with native awt menus. Use of selectItem() works fine for setting the default selected item, but itemStateChanged() is not working because none of the items ever equal the item returned from the ItemEvent, although looking at the code they should do. Does your example actually work for you ?

Comment: I hadn't tried it, but you're right - looks like ItemEvent.getItem() doesn't do what it says on the box. I've updated my answer with one I have actually compiled and tested.

Answer (score 1):

`CheckboxGroup` is not a `Component` (or, more specifically, a `MenuItem`), so you can't add it to the menu.  Instead, you can create a `CheckboxMenuItem`, but I think `CheckboxGroup` only works with instances of `Checkbox` so you'll have to write your own code to enforce single-selection.

If Swing is an option, you can instead use `JRadioButtonMenuItem` and `ButtonGroup`:

```
package com.example.checkboxmenu;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JRadioButtonMenuItem;

public class CheckboxMenu extends JFrame {

    public CheckboxMenu() {
        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        JMenu colorM = new JMenu("Color");
        JMenuItem quitM = new JMenuItem("Quit", KeyEvent.VK_Q);

        JRadioButtonMenuItem cb1 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Black", true);
        JRadioButtonMenuItem cb2 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Red", true);
        JRadioButtonMenuItem cb3 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Blue", true);
        JRadioButtonMenuItem cb4 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Green", true);

        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(cb1);
        group.add(cb2);
        group.add(cb3);
        group.add(cb4);

        setJMenuBar(mb);
        mb.add(file);
        mb.add(colorM);
        file.add(quitM);
        colorM.add(cb1);
        colorM.add(cb2);
        colorM.add(cb3);
        colorM.add(cb4);

        quitM.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400,300);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CheckboxMenu();
    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot use swing in this case. When i declare the check boxes i am adding them to the group in the same line. Im not sure what type of menu will accept a checkbox group

Comment: I think you'll have to implement CheckboxGroup's functionality yourself for CheckboxMenuItem.  It should be fairly straightforward, but you'll have to use a listener to update the status of the other checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Using swing instead of awt.

```
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
JMenu color = new JMenu("Color");

JCheckBoxMenuItem cb1 = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Black");
JCheckBoxMenuItem cb2 = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Red");
JCheckBoxMenuItem cb3 = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Blue");
JCheckBoxMenuItem cb4 = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Green");

ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
group.add(cb1);
group.add(cb2);
group.add(cb3);
group.add(cb4);

menuBar.add(cb1);
menuBar.add(cb2);
menuBar.add(cb3);
menuBar.add(cb4);

setJMenuBar(menuBar); // Set the JMenuBar of the JFrame
```

You can add any [AbstractButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html) to a [ButtonGroup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html#add(javax.swing.AbstractButton)).

Answer (score 0):

On OSX Java 7 (1.7.0_40) Julians answer doesnt quite work because the object returned by ItemEvent is actually a String rather than a CheckBoxItem, soiunds like a bug in OSX but got it working by modifying the itemStateChanged method

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class CheckboxMenuItemGroup implements ItemListener
{

    private Set<CheckboxMenuItem> items = new HashSet<CheckboxMenuItem>();

    public void add(CheckboxMenuItem cbmi) {
        cbmi.addItemListener(this);
        cbmi.setState(false);
        items.add(cbmi);
    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {

            String itemAffected = (String)e.getItem();
            for (CheckboxMenuItem item : items) {
                if (item.getLabel() != itemAffected) item.setState(false);
            }
        }
    }

    public void selectItem(CheckboxMenuItem itemToSelect) {
        for (CheckboxMenuItem item : items) {
            item.setState(item == itemToSelect);
        }
    }

    public CheckboxMenuItem getSelectedItem() {
        for (CheckboxMenuItem item : items) {
            if (item.getState()) return item;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Quite right - I hadn't compiled it myself, and it appears to behave the same way under JDK 1.7.0_45 in Linux now that I have tested it. I updated my code to reflect this, and fleshed out the example into something I have actually compiled and tested! You might want to use equals() for String comparison in your itemStateChanged() code, rather than != though.